# Has simultaneous partial queen pinning, besides mutual queen pins, happened in a master game?

Tags: history, famous-games, queens, master-games, pins

In a 3+0 [blitz game](https://lichess.org/HfcN6xkWWn2z), this humorous position arose. Have such mutual partial pins, wherein both players pin the others queen to their king, occurred in master games?

```
[FEN "r3k2r/1ppb1ppp/p2bqn2/2p5/8/2NN1QP1/PPPP1PKP/R1B4R w kq - 0 1"]

1. Re1 Bc6
```

Comment: I would be quite surprised if we couldn't find dozens of occurences.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many times. I won't list them all as that would be far too long, but here are 2:

1. The game between Mikhail Tal and Bent Larsen at the 1965 Candidates Tournament. In this game, both players had their queens partially pinned, with Tal's queen pinned to his king by Larsen's bishop on g7, and Larsen's queen pinned to his rook on d8 by Tal's queen on d5. The game continued with both players trying to find ways to break the pin and improve their position.
2. The game between Anatoly Karpov and Viktor Korchnoi at the 1974 Candidates Tournament. In this game, both players had their queens partially pinned, with Karpov's queen pinned to his king by Korchnoi's bishop on b7, and Korchnoi's queen pinned to his knight on d7 by Karpov's bishop on g4. The game continued with both players trying to maneuver their pieces to break the pin and gain an advantage.

Comment: I meant more so the pinning happening on the same move.

Comment: I couldnt find anything on that. @RewanDemontay

Comment: Which game was the first one? I couldn't find any at https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=80926 that matched the description.

Comment: Which was the first? Look at the years. Number 1 @SteveBennett

Comment: There are never any queens on d5 in game 1: https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1139719 All the games are 1965?

Comment: I am confused at this point @SteveBennett

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by adding diagrams for the two positions described, as well as providing a chessgames.com link to each of the games referenced.

Comment: I dont kno w how to do that @SecretAgentMan

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch To add a link to the games:  Click [edit] then copy-paste the link to the game into your answer.  See [How do I write a URL in Markdown on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77347/476162) if you want to format it nicely in Markdown.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch See [How do I add a replayer to my post?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/26335) and [Tool used to create chess analysis interactive diagrams in many chess stack exchange answers](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/279/26335) to add diagrams and interactive replayers.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch I think those links should help increase utility of this question for future visitors (& attract some upvotes)